# Meaning of "heavy reclaim pressure"

Tags: kubernetes, cgroups

In the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/11/26/qos-memory-resources/), it says "the cgroup’s processes are throttled and put under heavy reclaim pressure".
But what does "put under heavy reclaim pressure" mean from the perspective of Kubernetes and CGroup V2?

Comment: Explanation of what reclaim is within Linux: https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/mm/concepts.html#reclaim

Comment: **memory.high** specifies the memory usage throttle limit. This is the main mechanism to control a cgroup's memory use. If cgroups memory use goes over the high boundary specified here, the cgroups processes are throttled and put under heavy reclaim pressure. Refer to Official Kubernetes doc [How it works](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/05/05/qos-memory-resources/#cgroups-v2-memory-controller-interfaces-kubernetes-container-resources-mapping)